# Is it possible to override neo4j default behaviour on creating nodes and relationships?

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to override default neo4j behaviour for creating nodes and relatioships. What I want to achieve is something similar to this:

```
addNode(graphDb, node, properties) {
    performDefaultBehaviourToAddNode(graphDb, node, properties);
    performMyCustomOperations(graphDb, node, properties);
}
```

This code should be inserted (maybe) in a server plugin and executed each time a rest api call to neo4j create node operation is received (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-nodes.html).

Is it possible to achieve this with a server plugin or something similar?

I know that I could write extensions, but I want to use the original REST API methods to add nodes and relationships, in order to invoke it with py2neo.

Comment: Can you clarify?  You want to use the REST API, but you want the server on the other end to take some default action upon adding nodes, right?  Normally that would be done by extending the server, no?

Comment: You are perfectly right! What do you mean by extending the server?

Comment: I guess you can wrap the CRUD operations with some custom logic of yourself.

Comment: This is what I want, but I don't know how to achieve it! Server plugins seem to be insufficients.

Comment: Well, seems like you'd location the relevant implementation of this interface, then extend that class, then tell Neo4J to use your extension.   http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.1/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html

Comment: You can write a TransactionEventHandler, take a look at [this one](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid) by Stefan Armbruster for inspiration.